# Jenkins declarative pipeline ssh agent plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, sudo

I'm trying to use sshagent plugin to deploy to remote server.

when using below syntax, I'm getting

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
                    // some block
                    sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@<host_ip>"
                    sh "whoami"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

getting output:

```
[Pipeline] sh (hide)
+ whoami
jenkins
```

while I'm expecting to run script at the remote server using provided credentials !!

So, I had to run it this way

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
                    // some block
                    sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <host_ip> 'whoami && \
                    sudo apt update  && sudo apt install -y docker.io && \
                    sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu && \
                    source .bashrc && \
                    docker run -d nginx'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any "clean" way to run script on remote server with ubuntu instead of jenkins user ?

Edit:

I understand I need to run it under the ssh command not as separate sh script otherwise, it will run as jenkins and I'm able to do it in the scripted way as below.

That's why I'm asking if there's a better way to write it in the declarative way.

```
node {
   stage('Deploy'){
     def dockerRun = "whoami && \
            sudo apt update  && sudo apt install -y docker.io && \
            sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu && \
            source .bashrc && \
            docker run -d nginx "
            
     sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
       sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@<host_ip> '${dockerRun}' "
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your first code block appears to be two commands, an ssh remote no-op from agent to <host-ip>, then an agent local `whoami`. Tried the syntax generator?

Comment: why it runs `whoami` as jenkins not ubuntu while it's still inside the sshagent block ?

Comment: basically, you have added sshgent into agent of jenkins master, I think you should remove sshagent, and just run command : ssh -I ubuntu and do `whoami` command

Comment: @nurhun, you are running ssh FROM an SSH Agent TO <host ip>. Your agent is obviously launched as "jenkins". Refer to [shhagent example](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/#sshagent-ssh-agent), sub `uname` for `whomai`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you should select a credential which does reference the right remote username, as seen in the [SSH Agent Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/):

[image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin@master/docs/images/Screen_Shot_2012-10-26_at_12.25.04.png]

```json
node {
  sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l cloudbees 192.168.1.106 uname -a'
  }
}
```

Plus, I would execute only one script which would have the all sequence of commands you want to execute remotely.

Comment: that's exactly where I got the sample snippet.

Comment: @Nurhun Why not include the `credentials: ` part from that same snippet?

Comment: it works either ways, and syntax generator doesn't include it btw.

Answer (score 1):

A heredoc may be a more elegant solution:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
                    sh """
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <host_ip> << END
whoami
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y docker.io
sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
source .bashrc
docker run -d nginx
END
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you find the lack of indenting egregious, you can use bash and `<<-` to allow the leading **tabs** (not spaces unfortunately) to be ignored for the heredoc.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
                    sh """
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <host_ip> bash <<- END
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  whoami
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y docker.io
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  source .bashrc
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  docker run -d nginx
->  ->  ->  ->  ->  ->  END
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far this is the best way to do so, in-spite of repetition!

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
      stage('Deploy') {
          steps {

             sshagent(['nginx-ec2']) {
                 // some block
                 sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <remote_ip> 'whoami'"
                 sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <remote_ip> 'sudo apt update  && sudo apt install -y docker.io'"
                 sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <remote_ip> 'sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu'"
                 sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <remote_ip> 'source .bashrc'"
                 sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ubuntu <remote_ip> 'docker run -d -nginx'"
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Any chance for the first sh to do a scp of a script (which contains all your commands), and for the second sh, to ssh execute the script you just copied?